# Animating object's transparency in NLA editor

Tags: animation, node-editor, shaders, nla-editor

I would like to animate a short promo for a game I am making. I have various objects with different animations all set up nicely in the NLA editor. I would like to have some of those objects appear right before their animation. I have managed to keyframe the materials' transparency and see the keyframes on the timeline, but those animations don't appear as actions in the NLA editor and therefore I can't place them or move them around . Does anyone have any suggestions/workarounds?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you animated with nodes? Go to the animation layout while the animated node is selected, then you should be able to manipulate the keyframes.

Comment: Yes, I am able to manipulate the keyframes, but later I can't move them on the NLA editor to place them where I need them...

Comment: Hm - is the NLA an absolute must? Can you shift the keyframes to the proper place in the f-curve editor or dope sheet? That might be more straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know if this is the best answer, but you asked specifically about workarounds, and one thing I try to do when doing NLA animation is to keep actions all organized on a single armature.  As far as I'm concerned, an armature is the basic organizational unit of NLA work.

But then, how do you make a material value show up in an armature?  By using a driver, from a bone in the armature, to control the transparency:

[image]